# The 'importlib-resources>=1.0' distribution was not found and is required by virtualenv

Tags: python-venv

I am a newbie in python using mac. I encountered this error when
i installed venv in a project directory. I am using mac and python 3.9 insallted.

what is the solution?

The 'importlib-resources>=1.0' distribution was not found and is required by virtualenv

Answer (score 4):

Are you getting this error while trying to create a new virtual environment using the following command?

```
virtualenv virtualenv_name
```

If so, try the following

```
python3 -m virtualenv virtualenv_name
```

Answer (score 0):

As @anandxrfeu said, you can run the `virtualenv` command via `python3 -m`. You can also upgrade `setuptools` and then run `virtualenv env_name` directly:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```